# OP AMP as active negative resistors

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, active-components

Was reading about OP AMP and saw a article on "Active Negative Resistor" on wikipedia @ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_resistance.

Question to the gurus: How practical is this? Can I build a op amp circuit and replace one of the gain resistance with this "active" resistance and control the gain using voltage (like VCA)? The gain steps(between a finite gain) can be infinite in theory, if this works.

Comment: It's not obvious what "special magic" you think your suggestion would allow. Consider: You can produce an "active negative resistance" using opamp-based circuitry and control it's characteristics with a voltage or some other measurable parameter. Subject to the non ideality of the op amp the ANR produced would be about as "good" as one produced using a physical device such as a Gunn diode or similar. If you used it as you describe it just becomes part of a circuit using opp[amps and you have not effectively gained anything.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Lets say we have an op amp in inverting config with gain = -(r2/r1). R2 = 10K and R1 is variable resistance using above technique. Thus, if R1 becomes 10K, the gain = 0. Similarly, if R1 = 5K, the gain becomes 2.

Comment: No. -(10k/10k) = -1 and -(10k/(-10k)) = 1. And you can build a device whose gain can be varied under "programmed control" over any sensibly unlimited range using "normal" components. So far it is completely inobvious what this is meant to do that is in any way different than using other methods. It would be useful if you could explain this clearly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon how to "build a device whose gain can be varied under "programmed control" over any sensibly unlimited range using "normal" components". Please share any link so that I can learn? I want to build a stage 2 gain op amp circuit which can have a controlled (PWM voltage from PIC) gain from 1 to 100, with infinite steps in between (limited by the DAC of PIC).

Comment: @Anuf - [A few zillion VCA idea starters](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=voltage+controlled+amplifier&espv=2&biw=1189&bih=743&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=TgAMVZPJFI7f8AXivoE4&ved=0CD0QsAQ) - each links to a hopefully relevant page. See VCAs [**here**](http://www5b.biglobe.ne.jp/~houshu/synth/)

Answer (score 1):

*Question to the gurus: How practical is this? Can I build a op amp circuit and replace one of the gain resistance with this "active" resistance and control the gain using voltage (like VCA)?*

No - you can`t. I suppose, you are referring to the circuit called NIC, correct? Please note that this circuit offers a GROUNDED negative INPUT resistance only. Hence, it cannot compared with a classical passive ohmic resistor. More than that - how do you intend to "control" the value of this "active" resostor? It has a fixed value!

However, regarding your first question; This circuit is very practical. It is extensively used in oscillator and filter circuits. In these applications, this negative resistance can be placed in parallel to any (unwanted) ohmice resistance - thus reducing/compensating resistive damping properties because of [R1||(-R2)]>R1.

As another important application the NIC circuit is part of the two-opamp circuit called GIC (Generalized Impedance Converter), which is used to create an active inductance or an artificial block called FDNR (Frequency-dependent negative resistor). Both blocks are extensively used in active filters.